# Round trip transformation of ViewModel property in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-binding

I'm working on an ASP.NET MVC application and I'm trying to figure out how to support optimistic concurrency. The approach I'm working through right now is to have the web app retrieve an instance of an entity (just a POCO), and build a ViewModel from it. The ViewModel will include an `object UnderlyingEntity` property that holds the instance of the entity itself. I can put the `UnderlyingEntity` property in a hidden field in the view, then when the view is submitted, apply the changes to the `UnderlyingEntity`, and send it off to be updated. Since I've persisted my original entity instance in the hidden field, when I save I have the original timestamp to be used for the concurrency check.

The hurdles I'm trying to overcome with this are:

1. How do I do round-trip serialization/deserialization of the `UnderlyingEntity` property. I could serialize it easily enough in the view but how do I get it back to the original type when the form is posted? I think I need a ModelBinder or ValueProvider but I'm not sure exactly where to start.
2. I'd also like to encrypt/decrypt (edit: or hashing) the value so it's not sitting in the hidden field in plain text. If it were in plain text, it would basically be editable by a user through developer tools. I think if I solve #1, I can do this along with it.

Comment: That is a really bad idea. You have a view model - in the POST method you GET the original data from the DB based on the ID property, and you can compare the `TimeStamp` or each

Comment: Going with that, I would still need to persist the ID _and_ the timestamp of each record to save, right? It's impossible to "get the original data" because it may have already been modified by the time the POST occurs. So I need to hang onto the actual original timestamp and that leaves me with the same problem. I still wouldn't want the timestamp tampered with...though that would be less of concern in reality.

Comment: That's the whole point. You do need to get the original model based on the ID and compare the timestamps (because in the meantime, another user may have modified the data). And there are various ways you can protect against tampering of your hidden ID field if that is really a concern, such as hashing it and including a hidden field for the hashed value and then repeating the hash in the POST method and comparing it with the value of the hidden input

Comment: So I would send the VM including the IDs and timestamps off to the client. The client POSTS them back. I go retrieve the records by ID from the database. I replace the retrieved objects' timestamps with the timestamps sent back to me by the client. Now I set my changed properties on those retrieved objects (which may no longer be valid in its current state) and then try to save, which will fail if the record was modified. That reduces my view size, but requires extra reads from the db. What else makes this approach better? Also the only benefit of hashing over encrypting here is speed, right?

Comment: You do not _replace the timestamp_ (a `TIMESTAMP` is automatically updated by the db). You check if the time stamps match. If they do not then you know that another user has modified the data in the mean time. What you do then is up to you (notify the user what has been modified in the meantime, allow them to overwrite the other users data etc?)

Comment: And the benefit of hashing is not speed but the fact its a one way algorithm, and you do not need to store the encrypted value on the server so you can compare them. I'm not sure how you think that including a copy of the original data in the view can help you with concurrency - unless you get the data from the db again in the post method, you cannot determine if its been changed by another user in the meantime.

Comment: Storing a copy in the view just means avoiding reading it all from the DB again. Only storing the timestamp in the view helps with concurrency. As far as the timestamp comparison, your method sounds flawed. If you retrieve the record and compare the original timestamp to the retrieved timestamp in code, yes you can check if it was modified, but what happens if an update commits between your comparison and saving? You'll overwrite newer data. You'd have to lock the records when you read them in until you save. Better to compare timestamps in the update SQL where clause. Hence the replacement.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151993/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-xr280xr).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope. This is not how to do deal with concurrency in EF.

The best practice is the following steps:

- Add a new property of type row version or timestamp on your entity. This column will be used by EF to check the version of the row into your database when updating. If the value differs with the current value stored into the database then it will throw an exception.
- In your Razor wiew just store the value of your row version into a hidden field. (It will generate a Base 64 string like  Stephen Muecke spotted in comment)
- when user send back the data after editing to your application, you map your view model to your entity.
- When saving the data EF will throw an exception `DbUpdateConcurrencyException` , catch that exception. In the catch block, you do what you want.

To learn more about that go to this link => https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/handling-concurrency-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Comment: Not the just using `@Html.HiddenFor(m => youTimeStampProperty)` will generate the correct value (no need to convert it to a Base64 string - the method dos that)

Comment: Storing all the data client side was actually to be able to save the whole record without having to retrieve it from the db again. For concurrency, I have this set up on the entity framework end, but even if omitting the other columns, I would still want to encrypt my timestamp on the client side to prevent it from being modified.

Comment: @xr280xr by sending all the data to the view, Have you think about this security hole => http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2012/03/11/complete-guide-to-mass-assignment-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx

Comment: Thanks @CodeNotFound. Yes, but I believe that would be taken care of if all my extra data were encrypted in a single hidden field. Also in my case there's never going to be any data so sensitive that it would matter if they somehow cracked the encryption. It's just a deterrent from any temptation to mess around with it. Personally, I don't like the idea, but we're exploring all options at the moment.

Comment: You do it because you don't like to hit the database the data so just store the data into the cache (per user?) or user session and follow the best practice.